# Magento2.1 URL structure

Tags: magento-2.1, product, url

I want to show my products by below `URL` structure in Magento2.1:

`localhost/products/ID/product` title

What should I do?

Comment: Create a new router and replace the catalog frontend router with yours

Comment: Could you please explain it step by step?

Comment: @MilindSingh could you explain file by file and code by code, step by step?